# how to read vb random access file in java

Tags: java, vba

I write vba macros, that create file in random access mode:

```
Private Type Record
   id As Long
   name As String * 20
   status As String * 10
End Type

Private rec As Record
Private rows_count As Long
Private datfilePath As String

Private Sub writeButton_Click()
    datfilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "\data\datfile.dat"
    datfile = FreeFile()
    Open datfilePath For Random As #datfile Len = Len(rec)

    rows_count = Int(LOF(datfile) / Len(rec))

    rec.id = rows_count + 1
    rec.name = "test_name_" + Str(rows_count + 1)
    rec.status = "test_sta" + Str(rows_count + 1)

    Put #datfile, rows_count + 1, rec

    rows_count = Int(LOF(datfile) / Len(rec))

    Close #datfile
End Sub
```

how to read created file in java?

Comment: Do you know what file format that ends up using internally? How are the strings represented, how is the `Long` represented? Once you've worked that out, the rest should be fairly easy.

Comment: Check for a tutorial. Tip: `FileInputStream` is used to read from files in java.

Answer (score 0):

in result:

```
import java.io.*;

class ReadVBFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{ 
    try
    {
      String file = "datfile.dat";

      RandomAccessFile fh = new RandomAccessFile(file,"r"); 

      int file_length =(int)fh.length();
      int rec_length = 34;
      int rec_count = (int)(file_length/rec_length);

      System.out.println("file_length: " + file_length + "\r\n");
      System.out.println("rec_count: " + rec_count + "\r\n");

      for( int i_row=0; i_row < rec_count; i_row++ )
      {
        byte[] id_array = new byte[4];
        byte[] name_array = new byte[20];
        byte[] status_array = new byte[10];

        for( int i=0; i < 34; i++ )
        {
          byte b = fh.readByte();
          if( i < 4 )
          {

            id_array[i] = b;
          }
          else if( i < 24 )
          {
            name_array[i-4] = b;
          }
          else if( i < 34 )
          {
            status_array[i-24] = b;
          }

          fh.seek( i_row*34 + i + 1 );
        }

        // Long as Int
        int myInt = ((id_array[1] & 0xff) << 24) | ((id_array[2] & 0xff) << 16) | ((id_array[3] & 0xff) << 8) | (id_array[0] & 0xff);
        String name_value = new String(name_array);
        String status_value = new String(status_array);

        System.out.println( myInt + ", '" + name_value + "', '" + status_value + "'");
      }
    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println( "IOException: " + e.getMessage() );
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println( "Exception: " + e.getMessage() );
    }    
  }  
}
```